# How turn restrictions in k-shortest paths algorithm in pgRouting

Tags: postgresql, shortest-path, pgrouting

I want to turn restrictions in k-shortest paths in pgRouting.
I calculate one path using pgr_trsp function now, but it gives only one route. I need several shortests paths and turn restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgRouting does not have that functionality today. The best you can do today is write a wrapper that calls pgr_trsp multiple times.

There is additional work we want to do on trsp to convert it to boost along the lines of the work done on dijkstra in version 2.1.0 but it is not a priority at the moment without some funding.